# Failure to login to an Orbeon Forms application when using HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, orbeon, referrer

I have an Orbeon Forms v3.7.1 based application that fails when I try to login using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

I am using Apache as a proxy server connecting requests to a an application running on WebLogic 12.1.3. For various reasons, we recently had to migrate the Apache plugin module from mod_proxy to mod_weblogic.

For both modules, we have configured the module to map the incoming HTTPS requests to HTTP going to the WebLogic server. The main difference we noticed that seems to be causing the error is that the Referer header changed. When using the mod_proxy module, the Referer is listed as the Apache server using HTTP. When using the mod_weblogic module, the Referer is listed as the incoming Apache URL using HTTPS.

When using the mod_weblogic module, we get the following error in the Orbeon log when we try to login to the application. It seems to be failing while parsing the URL. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Here is the exception listed in the orbeon log file:

```
2015-03-19 22:28:40,340 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at line 20, column 46 of https://baseqa20151.delphi-tech.com:443/wl1213-test/baseqa20151/oasis2Portal/owsPortal/phs/get-navigation
org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: line 20, column 46 of https://baseqa20151.delphi-tech.com:443/wl1213-test/baseqa20151/oasis2Portal/owsPortal/phs/get-navigation: Fatal error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. 
https://baseqa20151.delphi-tech.com:443/wl1213-test/baseqa20151/oasis2Portal/owsPortal/phs/get-navigation, line 20, column 46: Fatal error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. 
at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils$ErrorHandler.fatalError(XMLUtils.java:306) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:351) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:281) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1459) 

    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1252) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1717) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108) 
    at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1201) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils.inputSourceToSAX(XMLUtils.java:350) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils.inputStreamToSAX(XMLUtils.java:335) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.URIProcessorOutputImpl.readURLToStateIfNeeded(URIProcessorOutputImpl.java:394) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsURIResolver.resolve(XFormsURIResolver.java:86) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsURIResolver.readURLAsDocument(XFormsURIResolver.java:117) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel.performDefaultAction(XFormsModel.java:660) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument.dispatchEvent(XFormsContainingDocument.java:1283) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainer.initializeModels(XFormsContainer.java:173) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument.initialize(XFormsContainingDocument.java:1525) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument.<init>(XFormsContainingDocument.java:181) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML.createCacheContainingDocument(XFormsToXHTML.java:326) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML.access$200(XFormsToXHTML.java:50) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML$2.read(XFormsToXHTML.java:152) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:453) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML.doIt(XFormsToXHTML.java:121) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML.access$000(XFormsToXHTML.java:50) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToXHTML$1.readImpl(XFormsToXHTML.java:80) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$6.read(ProcessorImpl.java:995) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorImpl.java:1178) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:350) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:355) 
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.xinclude.XIncludeProcessor.access$100(XIncludeProcessor.java:41) 
    ...
```

and here is the log record from the HTTP access.log file for this request:

```
10.192.16.82 - baseqa20151x [19/Mar/2015:22:28:40 -0400] "GET /wl1213-test/baseqa20151/oasis2Portal/owsPortal/phs/billing-account-policy-inquiry-admin HTTP/1.1" 500 215530
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is at this URL that returns the error (`https://baseqa20151.delphi-tech.com:443/wl1213-test/baseqa20151/oasis2Portal/owsPortal/phs/get-navigation`)? Do you know "who" is making a request to there? Should the request be made somewhere else? From what I can see in the exception, it seems that something the XForms needs to read that URL. Based on this, this would be what we consider to be an "internal request".

Comment: Maybe setting the `oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri ` property would help in this case (see http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-base#TOC-oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri)?

Comment: @avernet The request is from the web page to load another resource from the Orbeon application. I believe setting the `oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri` property will fix it, but I don't think the version of Orbeon we are using supports it. I double checked and see we are using version 3.6. Do you know if this is supported in version 3.6?

Comment: If it is not supported in 3.6, is there a way to download the 3.7.1 distribution that contains all of the dependent libraries in addition to the orbeon.jar? I downloaded the orbeon-dev-3.7.1.200905272119.jar file and stopped receiving this error, but the page fails to load, I assume because I am missing other dependent libraries.

Comment: You will need the entire WAR file. 3.7.1 is from June 1 2009, BTW, so all of this is terribly old. Here is a [link to the release](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5heq0wg7agc76x5/orbeon-dev-3.7.1.200905272119.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks @ebruchez  We plan to upgrade to the latest this year; we just need to budget time to convert our old-style xforms widgets to the new style of developing XBL components